# Use an object with this code? Processing

Tags: processing

How can I use the code I have now with an object where I can store the number of times the ball bounces and the color (when i add random color) and speed. Any pointers or tips would be greatful. I am new to OOP and it can get confusing for me. Thanks in advance

```
  float x;
  float y;
  float yspeed = 0;
  float xspeed = 0;
  float balldiameter = 10;
  float ballradius = balldiameter/2;

  void setup() {
  size (400,400);
  background (255);
  fill (0);
  ellipseMode(CENTER);
  smooth();
  noStroke();
  x = random(400);
  y = 0;
  }

  void draw() {
  mouseChecks();
  boundaryChecks();
  ballFunctions();
  keyFunctions();
  }

  void mouseChecks() {
    if (mousePressed == true) {
    x = mouseX;
    y = mouseY;
    yspeed = mouseY - pmouseY;
    xspeed = mouseX - pmouseX;
    }
  }

  void boundaryChecks() {
    if (y >= height - ballradius) {
      y = height - ballradius;
      yspeed = -yspeed/1.15;
    }
    if (y <= ballradius) {
      y = ballradius;
      yspeed = -yspeed/1.35;
    }
    if (x >= width -ballradius) {
      x = width -ballradius;
      xspeed = -xspeed/1.10;
    }
    if (x <= ballradius) {
      x = ballradius;
      xspeed = -xspeed/1.10;
     }
   }

   void ballFunctions() {
   if (balldiameter < 2) {
     balldiameter = 2;
     }
   if (balldiameter > 400) {
     balldiameter = 400;
     }
   ballradius = balldiameter/2;
   background(255); //should this be in here?
   ellipse (x,y,balldiameter,balldiameter);
   yspeed = yspeed += 1.63;
    // xspeed = xspeed+=1.63;
   y = y + yspeed;
   x = x + xspeed; 
   }
  void keyFunctions() {
    if (keyPressed) {
      if(keyCode == UP) {
      balldiameter +=1;
    }
    if (keyCode == DOWN) {
      balldiameter -=1;
      }
    }
   }
```

Comment: I think that you need to encapsulate everything in a function and decide which parts of the object you would like to set as variables.  Create an argument for each part you want to have as a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will probably want to do the following:
create a new file called `Ball.pde`
In that file write:

```
public class Ball {
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float yspeed;
    public float xspeed;
    public float diameter;
    public float radius;  

    public Ball(float initial_x, float initial_y, float diam) {
        this.x = initial_x;
        this.y = initial_y;
        this.xspeed = 0;
        this.yspeed = 0;
        this.diameter = diam;
        this.radius = diam/2;
    }

    public void move() {
       // movement stuff here
    }
}
```

This will give you a very basic `Ball` class. You can now use this class in your main sketch file like so:

```
Ball my_ball = new Ball(50, 50, 10);
```

you can access the balls members using:

```
my_ball.xspeed;
my_ball.yspeed;
my_ball.anything_you_defined_in_ball;
```

This will allow you yo store all relevent variables for the ball within its own class. you can even create more than 1.

```
Ball my_ball1 = new Ball(50, 50, 10);
Ball my_ball2 = new Ball(20, 20, 5);
```

Comment: Why Ball.ps? Shouldn't it be Ball.pde? Or Ball.java?

Answer (score 0):

Just to note that in Proccesing you don't need to create a new file for that, the code can go either in the same file (very bad practice as pointed below) or in a new tab of the IDE. If you are using the Processing IDE you can choose "new tab" from the arrow menu in the right and it will create the file for you. It will have ".pde" extension.

Comment: This should be a comment. Very bad practice to have all your classes in the same file. A new tab in the IDE is a new file.

Comment: I could not comment at that time... I said one don't need, not one should. Cause in Processing usually people are very new to programming (as i am) and i think sometimes simplicity can be more important. Anyway, thanks for pointing that. I'm always learning. Should i copy and paste it as a comment?

Comment: Ah i see, I dislike that not allowed to comment rule... Your answer is fine then :)